# WPF, Characters run from right-to-left when input text in TextBox

Tags: wpf

I have binding in TextBox

```
<TextBox x:Name="TbxActiveSourceNameSourceNameSourceName" IsEnabled="True" Text="{Binding ViewAudioAudio_ActiveSourceNameModel.ActiveSourceName_SourceName,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Padding="0,-2,0,0" Height="15" VerticalAlignment="top" Margin="127,10,0,0" FontSize="10" BorderBrush="#FF918D8D" TextAlignment="Center" Width="75px" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
```

But characters run from right-to-left. 
How do I must to characters run from left-to-right(normal) when I input words in textBox
Many Thanks

[image]

Comment: Thank you your reply. I tried but it's not OK

Comment: If it is maybe could be the binding.

Comment: How do you set this property: ViewAudioAudio_ActiveSourceNameModel.ActiveSourceName_SourceName?

Comment: It binding between model and View Audio

Comment: The fact (stated in one of your comments) that removing `PropertyChanged` fixes the problems indicates that you probably are doing something weird in the property setter of `ActiveSourceName_SourceName`. I.e. does that code try to manipulate or process the entered text in any further way? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5394170/numbers-displaying-backwards for a related problem.

Comment: Thank for your reply. I tried and do it the same but it's still not OK. What trouble bug :(

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question but if anyone runs into this issue it happens to deal with

```
<TextBox Text={..., UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

it seems that when the property changes via keystroke it automatically detects the property change and so it updates the property it's binding to as well. Because of this it resets the cursor to the very left of the textbox rather than leaving where it was last left off.

Or at least I've been only able to reproduce this issue by changing a textbox to textblock and then back to a textbox and changing the **UpdateSourceTrigger** to a type that isn't *PropertyChanged* and would correct the issue and have the text flow right to left.

Answer (score -1):

Set the `FlowDirection` property to `LeftToRight`. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.flowdirection#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_FlowDirection).

Comment: Try setting the `HorizontalContentAlignment` to `Left` aswell.

Comment: It's still not OK. 
If I remove UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in Binding, the text will runs left-to-right. But I cannot remove it.
Please help me

Comment: What does your property return?

Comment: it returns the text on window when I input